# Numpy Stack :: all input arrays must have the same shape

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, deep-learning, neural-network

> I was Trying to to Calculate initial embedding of all data frame which is first step to implement my GNN which is Heterogeneous in nature.I have used twitter msg data set in the task I loaded it in following way

```
load_path = '/Users/hemangjiwnani/Desktop/Projects/Paper1/KPGNN/datasets/Twitter/'
save_path = '/Users/hemangjiwnani/Desktop/Projects/Paper1/KPGNN/datasets/Twitter/'

# load dataset`enter code here`
p_part1 = load_path + '68841_tweets_multiclasses_filtered_0722_part1.npy'
p_part2 = load_path + '68841_tweets_multiclasses_filtered_0722_part2.npy'
#"./datasets/Twitter/68841_tweets_multiclasses_filtered_0722_part1.npy"

df_np_part1 = np.load(p_part1, allow_pickle=True)
df_np_part2 = np.load(p_part2, allow_pickle=True)
```

### Then I have created a data frame of the same with the help of following code

```
df_np = np.concatenate((df_np_part1, df_np_part2), axis = 0) #Axis = 0 means horizontal
print("Loaded data.")

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_np, columns=["event_id", "tweet_id", "text", "user_id", "created_at", "user_loc",\
"place_type", "place_full_name", "place_country_code", "hashtags", "user_mentions", "image_urls", "entities", 
"words", "filtered_words", "sampled_words"])
print("Data converted to dataframe.")
print(df.shape)
print(df.head(5))
```

### Which was having following output

```
Loaded data.
Data converted to dataframe.
(68841, 16)
event_id  ... sampled_words
0        0  ...            []
1        0  ...            []
2        0  ...            []
3        0  ...            []
4        0  ...            []

[5 rows x 16 columns]
```

### This Function Below is raising a error while returning

```
def documents_to_features(df):
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm"
#nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()
features = df.filtered_words.apply(lambda x: nlp(' '.join(x)).vector).values
-->return np.stack(features, axis=0)
```

### ERROR

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2e8bc5e83009> in <module>()
----> 1 d_features = documents_to_features(df)
      2 print("Document features generated.")
      3 t_features = df_to_t_features(df)
      4 print("Time features generated.")
      5 combined_features = np.concatenate((d_features, t_features), axis=1)

1 frames
<ipython-input-9-b772a7744232> in documents_to_features(df)
      3     #nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()
      4     features = df.filtered_words.apply(lambda x: nlp(' '.join(x)).vector).values
----> 5     return np.stack(features, axis=0)

<__array_function__ internals> in stack(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in stack(arrays, axis, out)
 425     shapes = {arr.shape for arr in arrays}
 426     if len(shapes) != 1:
 -->  427         raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
 428 
 429     result_ndim = arrays[0].ndim + 1

 ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

Comment: did you try to print a list of the shapes of all the arrays in the features? are you trying to stack arrays with different shapes? cause that shouldn't work. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes.I tried checking the shape of array all the arrays are similar only. I do want to stack them for further use

Comment: When u check shape you get following output                                                                   `Shape of arrays:- (68841,)
Size of arrays 68841`